# My training Data and labels have different numpy array shapes. It is disrupting my training

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have an image based database That I am working with and am attempting to convert it to a numpy array. Which I would then use for a cGAN input. I have tried using multiple codes and they are all giving me dimesnionality issue. Not sure what to do

```
training_data = []
IMG_SIZE = 32
datadir = 'drive/My Drive/dummyDS'  
CATEGORIES = ['HTC-1-M7', 'IPhone-4s', 'iPhone-6', 'LG-Nexus-5x', 
              'Motorola-Droid-Max', 'Motorola-Nexus-6', 'Motorola-X', 
              'Samsung-Galaxy-Note3', 'Samsung-Galaxy-S4', 'Sony-Nex-7']

def create_training_data():
    i=0
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path=os.path.join(datadir,category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        for img in os.listdir(path):
          img_array=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
          new_array=cv2.resize(img_array,(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
          training_data.append([new_array,class_num])
          plt.imshow(img_array,cmap="gray")
          plt.imshow(new_array,cmap="gray")
          plt.show() 
create_training_data()
```

```
X=[]
y=[]
random.shuffle(training_data)

for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
pickle_out = open("X.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(X, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

y = np.array(y)
pickle_out = open("y.pickle","wb")
pickle.dump(y, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()
```

```
y = to_categorical(y)

# saving the y_labels_one_hot array as a .npy file
np.save('y_labels_one_hot.npy', y)
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=2./11)
```

X_train.shape=(32,32,32,3)  while y_train.shape= (32,4,2)

Now in training I am getting

```
real_labels=to_categorical(Y_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size].reshape(-1,1),num_classes=10)
        d_loss_real = discriminator.train_on_batch(x=[X_batch, real_labels],
                                                   y=real * (1 - smooth))
```

```
ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(32, 32, 32, 3), (256, 10)]
```

Comment: Hi @Mr. Johnny Doe , please provide a minimum reproducible block of code that can simulate your whole process.

Answer (score 0):

**`tensorflow.keras.imagedatagenerator.flow_from_directory`** should simplify your task.

It does almost everything you do using the code you mentioned, in a simpler way, including `Splitting` the Data

Code mentioned demonstrates how to use it, along with the **detailed explanation** of each line of code :

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, # Normalizes every pixel value
    validation_split=0.2) # Setting Validation Data as 20% of Total Data

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    datadir, # Traverses through all the Sub Folders (Category) inside this dir
    target_size=(img_height, img_width), # Sets the Image Size
    batch_size=batch_size, # Generates batches of `batch_size`
    class_mode='categorical', # Will Consider Labels as Categorical
    shuffle = True, # Shuffles the Data
    subset='training') # Considers 80% as training data

# Since we don't have separate directory for Validation Data and since we want the Total Data to be Partitioned, we should use "train_datagen"
validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    datadir , # Should use the Same Dir as Training for Splitting
    target_size=(img_height, img_width), 
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle = True, # Shuffles the Data
    subset='validation') # Considers 20% as Validation data

# Then you can train the model using the code mentioned below
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs = nb_epochs)
```

Hope this will resolve your issue of different `Shapes` as it will ensure that `Features` and `Labels` will be of same shape. Please share more information if this approach is resulting in Error.

Happy Learning!